# Get list of elements that are divisible by 3 or 5 from 1 - 1000

Tags: scala

I'm trying to write a functional approach in scala to get a list of all numbers between 1 & 1000 that are divisible by 3 or 5

Here is what I have so far :

```
  def getListOfElements(): List[Int] = { 
  val list = List()

    for (i <- 0 until 1000) {
        //list.
  } 
  list match {
    case Nil => 0
  } 
  list
}
```

The for loop seems like an imperative approach and I'm not sure what to match on in the case class. Some guidance please ?

Comment: Is this [fizzbuzz](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/02/why-cant-programmers-program.html)?

Comment: @om-nom-nom its http://projecteuler.net/problem=1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's how I would do it with a `for` expression.

```
for( i <- 1 to 1000 if i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0) yield i
```

This gives:

```
 scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 12, 15, 18, 20, 21...
```

Here's another approach filtering on a `Range` of numbers.

```
scala> 1 to 1000
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Range.Inclusive = Range(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10...


scala> res0.filter(x => x % 3 == 0 || x % 5 == 0)
res1: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 12, 15, 18, 20, 21...
```

If you really want a `List` on the return value use `toList`. e.g. `res0.toList`.

Comment: filter is not another approach to for+if, it is exactly the same. And don't use `x toList`. That is a postfix operator, which is error prone and therefore hided behind a flag in 2.10.

Answer (score 3):

```
(Range(3, 1000, 3) ++ Range(5, 1000, 5)).toSet.toList.sorted
```

Sorted can be omitted.

Answer (score 3):

another aproach:

```
(1 to 1000).filter(i => i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like Brian beat me to it :)

Just thought I'd mention that a Stream might be more preferable here for better performance:

```
val x = (1 until 1000).toStream           //> x  : scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(1, ?)
x filter (t=>(t%3==0)||(t%5==0))          //> res0: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(3, ?)
```

Comment: toStream is an overkill ;) it is just 1000 elements.

Comment: Well, no harm I guess. Makes it instantly scalable if you're using much larger ranges :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem from projecteuler.net also wants a sum of those numbers at the end.

"Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000."

```
object prb1 {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val retval = for{ a <- 1 to 999
                      if a % 3 == 0 || a % 5 == 0
    } yield a
    val sum = retval.reduceLeft[Int](_+_)
    println("The sum of all multiples of 3 and 5 below 1000 is " + sum)
  }
}
```

The correct answer should be **233168**

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 0):

No any answer without division or list recreation. No any answer with recursion.

Also, any benchmarking?

```
@scala.annotation.tailrec def div3or5(list: Range, result: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
  var acc = result
  var tailList = list
  try {
    acc = list.drop(2).head :: acc   // drop 1 2 save 3
    acc = list.drop(4).head :: acc   // drop 3 4 save 5
    acc = list.drop(5).head :: acc   // drop 5 save 6 
    acc = list.drop(8).head :: acc   // drop 6 7 8 save 9
    acc = list.drop(9).head :: acc   // drop 9 save 10
    acc = list.drop(11).head :: acc  // drop 10 11 save 12
    acc = list.drop(14).head :: acc  // drop 12 13 14 save 15 
    tailList = list.drop(15)         // drop 15             
  } catch {
    case e: NoSuchElementException => return acc // found
  }
  div3or5(tailList, acc) // continue search  
}

div3or5(Range(1, 1001), Nil)
```

**EDIT**

```
scala> val t0 = System.nanoTime; div3or5(Range(1, 10000001), Nil).toList; 
(System.nanoTime - t0) / 1000000000.0
t0: Long = 1355346955285989000
res20: Double = 6.218004
```

One of answers that looks good to me:

```
scala> val t0 = System.nanoTime; Range(1, 10000001).filter(i => 
i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0).toList; (System.nanoTime - t0) / 1000000000.0
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Another one:

```
scala> val t0 = System.nanoTime; (Range(1, 10000001).toStream filter (
(t: Int)=>(t%3==0)||(t%5==0))).toList ; (System.nanoTime - t0) / 1000000000.0
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

First one:

```
scala> val t0 = System.nanoTime; (for( i <- 1 to 10000000 if i % 3 == 0 || 
i % 5 == 0) yield i).toList; (System.nanoTime - t0) / 1000000000.0
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Why Scala does not optimize for example Vector -> List?