# Scala for loop value example

Tags: scala, for-loop

How to do it this problem in Scala? Do it in For-loop.

sum of all the multiples of 3 and 5 below 1000;

Example: 1*3+2*5+3*3+4*5+5*3+6*5 ... so on 999*3+1000*5 = How much?

Comment: This has been asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13845166/get-list-of-elements-that-are-divisible-by-3-or-5-from-1-1000/27612148#27612148  This is problem #1 from Project Euler and if you want someone to answer it for you there is a web site with scala solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that 1000*5 is a multiple of 5 below 1000. 1000*5 is 5000 which is not below 1000.

It seems like what you want is:

```
(1 to 1000).filter(x => x % 3 = 0 || x % 5 == 0).sum
```

Which doesn't use a "for-loop". A lot of people would cringe at such a term, scala doesn't really have for-loops. if MUST use the for construct, perhaps you would write

```
 (for (x <- 1 to 1000 if x % 3 == 0 || x % 5 == 0) yield x).sum
```

which is exactly the same thing as above.

you could also (though I would not recommend it) use mutation:

```
var s = 0
for { x <- 1 to 1000 } { if(x % 3 == 0 || x % 5 == 0) s += x }
s
```

which could also be

```
var s = 0
for { x <- 1 to 1000 if (x % 3 == 0 || x % 5 == 0) } { s += x }
s
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the principles of functional programming you would do it recursive - better you can use tail recursion (sorry that the example is not that good but it's pretty late).

```
def calc(factorB:Int):Int = {
    if(factorB+1 >= 1000)
        3*factorB+5*(factorB+1)
    else
        3*factorB+5*(factorB+1)+calc(factorB+2)
}
```

In a for-loop you can do it like

```
var result = 0
for(i <- 1 to 1000){
    result += i*(i%2==0?5:3)
}
```

After the for-loop result yields the calculated value. The downside is that you're using a var instead of val. Iam not sure if the statement i%2==0?5:3 is valid in scala but I don't see any reasons why it shouldn't.